# reading from the output of a process into a byteArray

Tags: scala, io

I have been struggling a bit trying to avid blocking IO when I execute a external command many different times.

I finally was able to get it to work (after reading many pages, trying
different methods, many of them resulting in blocking io).

My current solution (below) works. But I have to predefine the byteArray with the output (newArray) and I have to give it a size. The problem is,
when I give it a fixed size (say 1000), it only reads the first 1000 bytes.
My problem seems to be scoping and my poor understanding of immutability of arrays. Is there any cleaner way to read the output of the command into a bytearray that grows as much as necessary?

Or, is there a better way to convert the InputStream in into a byteArray newBytes?

```
bytes is a predefined byteArray

var newBytes = new Array[Byte](bytes.length);

def readJob(in: InputStream) {
  newBytes = Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte).toArray

  in.close();

}
def writeJob(out: OutputStream) {

  out.write(bytes)
  out.close()
}

val io = new ProcessIO(
  writeJob,
  readJob,
  _=> ())

val pb = Process(command)
val proc = pb.run(io)
val exitCode = proc.exitValue // very important, so it waits until it completes
```

Thanks you very much in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following to compile.

```
val newBytes = ArrayBuffer[Byte]()

def readJob(in: InputStream) {
  newBytes.appendAll(Stream.continually(in.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte).toArray)
  in.close()
}

def writeJob(out: OutputStream) {
  out.write(newBytes.toArray)
  out.close()
}

// the rest of the code is unchanged
```

I'm not convinced this is the best approach, but it might be workable with minimal adjustments to what you've already got.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed